# Javascript For Loop Closures...Can't seem to wrap my head around this

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

How can I make this work?

```
// Phrases

var phrases = new Array();
phrases[0] = 'Phrase 1';
phrases[1] = 'Phrase 2';
phrases[2] = 'Phrase 3';

for (var i = 0; i < phrases.length; i++) {  
   var content = phrases[i];        
   $('#phrase').html(content).slideDown('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');    
};
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<p id="phrase"></p>
```

Passing the **content** variable into the **html()** function I noticed that **content** is always equal to the last phrase in the array, and the loop runs the slide / delay / fade functions 3 times.

I know that this is something to do with closures inside a for loop and I've looked at countless examples, but I just can't get my head around it. Can someone solve and explain this one to me please?

**EDIT:** Apologies for being unclear before, I have edited this question to include the HTML and the array in question.

**Functionality:** Different phrases are held in the **phrases[]** array, I would like to insert the phrase into the `<p>` element, then slide that element down, leave it on screen for a second, then fade it out. Then I would like to move on to the next phrase in the **phrases[]** array and perform the same functions.

Comment: what the loop is really doing is selecting the element with that id and writing to it every iteration of the loop, so it is overwriting it every time until the final iteration.  Explain what it is you are wanting to do

Comment: Thanks Crayon, I have updated the question to reflect what I am trying to do.

Comment: Doesn't delay(1000) actually return control NOW and insert a task to occur 1 second from now, or 1000 seconds from now (prototype takes seconds)?  If so, the loop will execute very quickly, and then after 1 second all the queued up screen changes will occur very quickly. Also, I'm not sure the line with delay() is syntactically valid, at least when used with prototype.js.  I haven't tried it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have an issue with closures, it is just setting the `innerHTML` to `content` on every iteration, which doesn't take into account the effects which need to be completed first.

```
var showPhrase = function(phrases, start) {
    start = start || 0;
    var showNext = function() {
        $('#phrase')
         .html(phrases[start])
         .slideDown('slow')
         .delay(1000)
         .fadeOut('slow', function() {
            start++;
            if (start < phrases.length) {
                showNext();
            }
        });
    }
    showNext();
}

showPhrase(['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/G9RvQ/).

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your response. This works of course, but I was hoping to display the phrases which are held in the phrases array as apposed to the letters a, b, and c.

Comment: Sorry keyboard issue there - how could I amend your script so that it would read the phrases from the array itself?

Comment: @FrediDoo: check out **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/G9RvQ/2/)**

Comment: @FrediDoo Sorry, I was out to lunch. It is trivial to replace my example array with your own.

Comment: Alrighty, cheers Alex. I'm really not great with Javascript at all so definitely wouldn't have got it on my own. Take it easy :)

Comment: @FrediDoo Feel free to give me the big green tick to say *thanks* :)

Comment: @qwertymk I don't know why I didn't do that originally. I edited my question, thanks.